# Why was my question about Cantrips put on hold?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

My question was put on hold for being off topic. More specifically because I supposedly ask about the game.

This is not true at all and even edited it in for more clarification:

> Whats the difference between a Cantrip and a normal spell **in the
>   normal tabletop game lorewise** and how powerful are they in comparison?

[How do Cantrips work exactly and what are they?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133973/how-do-cantrips-work-exactly-and-what-are-they)

The video game was just mentioned at the beginning of the question and nothing more so what is the problem here? Also i reworded it before it was put on hold, so several people voted even after the edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My question was incorrectly put on-hold for "being about video games"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6694/my-question-was-incorrectly-put-on-hold-for-being-about-video-games)

Comment: Note: The question seems to have been reopened now.

Answer (score 3):

As V2Blast noted in the comments, your question has since been reopened.

But to answer the actual question anyway: this is essentially [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

The way the system works is that when there are multiple close votes cast for multiple reason, only the most-voted-upon-reason is displayed. Since it takes 5 votes to close a question (unless done-so by a diamond mod), if 3 of those votes are 'off-topic' and 2 are 'unclear' then the message/reason displayed on the close banner would be the 'off-topic' one.

For example: before your edit that clarified you were asking about the TTRPG rules, not the video game, there were 4 Votes to Close (VtC) as off-topic. After that edit one of those off-topic votes was retracted, leaving 3 off-topic VtC.

I don't know what the last 2 votes were but whether they were 'unclear' or 'too broad' or what-have-you, since there were still 3 'off-topic' votes, they system would still close the question as off-topic.

It is a bit of an unfortunate and sometimes annoying side effect because vote reasons can't be changed once cast and can't be cast again once retracted.