# Would a question about finding art resources of a very specific style/theme/content would be on topic here?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic

I'm looking for concept artwork to support an RPG campaign, and I'm having trouble finding more art in the same vein as a particular image I really like (specifically a particular character model for lizardfolk). **Is RPG.SE a place where I can share a picture, describe what about it I want more of, and ask for help finding similar image resources?**

I'm imagining that answers could be framed like, "That's a Dawnforge lizardfolk, they have a lot of art in [publication]," or "[Site] specialises in humanoid reptilian art," or "You should have luck with image searches for [search phrase]."

Comment: Is asking on the sci-fi stack out of the question?

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton I could try, but they hate anything which could possibly be construed as vaguely list-like. Though they *do* like pictures...

Comment: @BESW They hate anything vaguely list-like.  I'm beginning to sense a theme ;-).

Answer (score 6):

I'm erring on this being off topic, like mxyzplk.

This falls under the same kind of category as [campaign research questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1604/1204), which resulted in a new content guideline to rule out real-world topics that had nothing to do with RPGs. Basically: questions must elicit a better/different/more specific answer from an RPG expert than an expert on a different real-world topic.

There will be some requests where an answerer can say:

> Oh, hey! That's {obscure creature acknowledged only in certain D&D articles}. You can find more art of those in {place}.

... and those questions will elicit a better/different/more specific answer from the RPG crowd.

However, *most* requests are *probably* just going to be a beast that appears in a myriad of art forms and sources, including all over DeviantArt, with none of it necessarily requiring any RPG expertise to dig up, other than the fact RPG experts might be one of the kinds of people to have experience trying to dig up reference art, but that skill is tangential to our domain.

If we allow the former but not the latter, we'd have to identify an objective guideline to draw *that does not depend on the question being answered first.*

Answer (score 5):

It would be off topic.

Remember the standard Venn diagram of what's on topic.  "More art like this" is not a meaningful overlap with "RPG Experts," it's either anyone who can use Google image search or more suitable for art experts.