# Are questions about historical material relevant here?

Tags: discussion

Say, I wanted to know how to play a paladin and wanted to read up on Templar Knights.  Would a request for good historical accounts that can be applied to RPG relevant?

I would say no, go to [history.stackexchange.com](https://history.stackexchange.com/) but that site does not exists -- yet.  So, should I ask (get flamed, get down votes, get question closed, grow more bitter ^_- ) or not?

Comment: You might be interested to know (if you didn't already) that [history.se] is in Beta now.

Comment: @Iszi: Thank you for the head's up but I was aware of it.

Answer (score 3):

See: [Are campaign research questions on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/570/campaign-research-questions)

My take on it remains:

1) You should tie all such questions directly to an RPG, or RPG use-case. If you were looking to play a D&D paladin, you should be willing to accept D&D-based source material... A World of Darkness character should be willing to accept World of Darkness "history."

2) The level of detail should be appropriate to an RPG.

Comment: I run systemless games so systems are kinda useless to me. Not to say that D&D or GURPS or XXX cannot have a good take on templar knights, just that if it is just rules I have no interest in the matter.

Comment: @Sardathrion "RPG" in this instance has nothing to do with rules, but rather setting. If you are not playing an established setting, then you will still be tying it to your existing setting (although, that may be relevant). Point two will be more relevant to you: Scope. Asking how to roleplay a templar in a historical setting should be fine; looking for the nitty gritty on the daily grind of a templar is probably out of scope (IMO).

Comment: Right, I see what you mean. ^_-  And hence the question here before posting it on the main site.

Comment: I'd dispute some of the assumptions implied by (2), since level of detail can vary *wildly* when you get away from "kill them and take their stuff + roleplay" mainstream games, enough that it's not a reasonable restriction. If you're playing homebrewed "Templar Nights: The Roleplaying Soap Opera", then a lot of nitty-gritty is relevant. So, back to (1): justify the question with a good explanation of what RPG problem you are trying to solve! As a rule of thumb, it should be informative enough that non-historical-detail answers that you didn't think of could be valid solutions to your problem.

Comment: @Seven -- I suspect we have different definitions of nitty gritty... The level of detail required for a soap opera, for example, is still several steps away from the maximum detail level available. The point is: If you're asking it here, you should expect that the answers will not come from professional historians with citations from primary sources. It will come from role players with an active interest in adapting history to the medium, and will likely have some streamlining/distortion because of it.

Comment: @AceCalhoon When you put it like this: "If you're asking it here, you should expect that the answers will not come from professional historians" I totally agree. That's an excellent rule of thumb, actually.

Comment: +1. View http://i.stack.imgur.com/BngZk.png and replace the good circle with "Players and GMs of RPGs."